# jpa repositofy findall() returns empty list

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm practicing making web pages using spring boot.

I created an h2 DB and connected it, and I want to show the name properties of the members table as a list on my web page.

I created the findall() method, but only an empty list is returned. What's wrong with my code?

[my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiX8E.png)

#### MemberRepository

```
package com.example.testproject.store.h2.repository;

import com.example.testproject.store.h2.domain.Members;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Members, Integer> {

}
```

#### MemberService

```
package com.example.testproject.store.h2.service;

import com.example.testproject.store.h2.domain.Members;

import java.util.List;

public interface MemberService {
    List<Members> getAll();

}
```

#### MemberServiceImpl

```
package com.example.testproject.store.h2.service;

import com.example.testproject.store.h2.domain.Members;
import com.example.testproject.store.h2.repository.MemberRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.lang.reflect.Member;
import java.util.List;

@Service(value = "memberServiceImpl")
public class MemberServiceImpl implements MemberService {
    @Autowired
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;

    public List<Members> getAll(){
        return memberRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

#### MemberController

```
package com.example.testproject.controller;

import com.example.testproject.store.h2.domain.Members;
import com.example.testproject.store.h2.service.MemberService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
@RestController
public class MemberController {
    @Autowired
    private MemberService memberService;
    @GetMapping(value = "/members")
    public List<Members> getAll() {
        List<Members> users = memberService.getAll();
        return users;
    }

    /*@GetMapping(value = "/members")
    public List<Members> getAll() throws Exception {
        return memberService.getAll();
    }*/

}
```

#### Members(Entity)

```
package com.example.testproject.store.h2.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "members")
public class Members {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

I want to show the name properties of the members table as a list on my web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the getter setter method in entity class either you need to 1:-define getter setter method for each field or
2:-you need to add  lombook dependency in pom.xml file and add @Data annootation on top of entity class so that when spring uses your entity can set and get the value from database and if you dontot want to give id explicitly then add @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) so that spring automatically increase you id

Comment: if you find the solution please mark this uestion as accepted

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed getters and setters in your `Entity`
Class just add them by using `@Data` annotation and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You missed getters and setters for the fields in your Entity

You do not need any library, you can write it by yourself.

Otherwise, even if you use `lombok`, you should avoid to use `@Data` annotation on `Entity`, because it could lead to [errors](https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/) with default implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`. Instead you can use annotations `@Getter` and `@Setter` on the class.