# Spring Boot JPA returns empty list for findAll() of entity with composite key

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a hard time getting data from the Postgres DB schema which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.mm_enterprise (
                                      systemcode varchar(64) NOT NULL,
                                      lid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                                      euid int8 NOT NULL,
                                      CONSTRAINT pk_enterprise PRIMARY KEY (systemcode, lid, euid)
);
CREATE INDEX mm_enterprise1 ON public.mm_enterprise USING btree (euid);
```

and entity for that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mm_enterprise")
public class EUID {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "lid", nullable = false)
    private String lid;

    @Column(name = "systemcode", nullable = false)
    private String systemcode;

    @Column(name = "euid", nullable = false)
    private Integer euid;

    public EUID() {
    }

    public String getSystemcode() {
        return systemcode;
    }

    public void setSystemcode(String systemcode) {
        this.systemcode = systemcode;
    }

    public Integer getEuid() {
        return euid;
    }

    public void setEuid(Integer euid) {
        this.euid = euid;
    }

    public String getLid() {
        return lid;
    }

    public void setLid(String lid) {
        this.lid = lid;
    }
}
```

Repository for `findAll()` looks like

```
@Repository
public interface EUIDRepository extends JpaRepository<EUID, String> {

    List<EUID> findAll();
}
```

but when I will run it the list will come empty. Hibernate is set to validate as well output SQL, which looks like

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        euid0_.lid as lid1_0_,
        euid0_.euid as euid2_0_,
        euid0_.systemcode as systemco3_0_ 
    from
        mm_enterprise euid0_
```

and that query works fine when I will execute it directly on the DB.

Any thoughts on what I have skipped? Postgres version is 13.8

PS.

It looks like that `lid` can't be annotated as `@Id` for some reason. DB is a 3rd-party DB so I'm not able to add `id SERIAL` to that table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jpa repositofy findall() returns empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078830/jpa-repositofy-findall-returns-empty-list)

Comment: @GastónSchabas i have setter and getter in the entity. Do I need to add annotation?

Comment: @GastónSchabas added more info to the OP

Comment: I haven't used hibernate for some time. Maybe this post about [Hibernate Identifiers](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers) could help you to solve your porblem

Comment: The database table has a composite primary key: PRIMARY KEY (systemcode, lid, euid) Your entity class should provide the same. Either using Embeddable and EmbeddedId annotations or IdClass annotation. More details and examples on the above mentioned Baeldung page.

Comment: @Mar-Z OK, so should I do `@Embeddable` for all 3 fields then? I'm not familiar wth that approach for creating an id.

Comment: I would rather do it with `@IdClass` Here is yet another Baeldung page with examples: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys

Comment: @Mar-Z  That worked. Thanks!  Posted an answer for both approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mar-Z mentioned in the comments there are 2 ways to get it the right way.

**#1 Using `@IdClass` (preferred)**

Create ID class as

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class SystemcodeLidEuidId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -909206262878526790L;

    private String lid;
    private String systemcode;
    private Long euid;
}
```

and then entity as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mm_enterprise")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(SystemcodeLidEuidId.class)
public class EUID implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -909206262878526790L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "lid")
    private String lid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "systemcode")
    private String systemcode;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "euid")
    private Long euid;

}
```

**#2 Using `@@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId`**

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class OrderEntryPK implements Serializable {

    private String lid;
    private String systemcode;

}
```

and an entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "mm_enterprise")
public class EUID {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderEntryPK id;

    @Column(name = "euid", nullable = false)
    private Long euid;

}
```